# How to solve this first order response of RC circuit question?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

As I learned about the first-order response of the RC circuit, there is one question that I'm quite confused about and don't know how to solve. I hope someone can guide me through the question.

The question is the switch in Figure 1 has been in position ‘A’ for a long time. At t=0, the switch moves to ‘B’.  Determine v(t) for t >0 across the capacitor and calculate its value at t= 4 s. Show your calculations clearly and draw the circuit diagram for switch positions ‘A’ and ‘B’ accordingly.

[image: This is the circuit]

As I have done is for the left-hand side which calculates the Vc(0) which is

[image]

then for the right-hand side, I have simplified the resistors to become something like this and I'm not sure how to proceed again.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?  Can you get through the initial state just before t=0 ?  That is your starting point, then you have a capacitor that either charges or discharges.

Comment: @Nedd hii, as i have done is for the left-hand side which calculates the Vc(0) which is 60 x [60k/(60k+45k)] = 34.286V
then for the right-hand side, I have simplified the resistors (refer to the post, I have updated my steps while waiting for someone to guide me next T.T

Comment: @NekoLim Can you consider how you might Thevenize the -90 V source on the right with the 20k and 110k resistor divider pair? Just like you did on the left?

Comment: OK, though the battery on the left is not relevant when the switch is thrown at t=0, the cap itself will have the voltage. For the right side find the Thevenin's voltage.

Comment: Once you know the capacitor's starting voltage, the final voltage, and the RC time constant of the circuit use the capacitor transient (voltage change) formula to find the voltage on the cap over time.